# Jupyter Notebook "save as..." => file can not be opened

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have saved a jupyter notebook code yesterday with "save as" and it's name on my computer desktop. I wanted to open i today on jupyter notebook but this is not anymore a jupyter notebook. It is just a code without any operations in it.

[image: Code]

Is there something, where i can get it to jupyter notebook again?

Comment: The above file is opened as json. Save the file with .ipynb and try opening it.

Answer (score 1):

just rename the file with a .ipynb extension then Jupyter or VScode will recognize it as an actual notebook.